# how to add older post to new wordpress post with new post?

Tags: posts

I have my older post wordpress with domain, example1.com where my domain example1.com already deleted and I only can access my phpadmin and cpanel.

and a few ago, I make a new website with domain example2.com where in my new website I already have 10 new post.

How I can add my older post to my new domain ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your old database and uploads folder, you can install WordPress and give it that database.

Then, you can use the wordpress importer/exporter to export the posts, then upload it to your new site using the same plugin.

If your old site is much larger, it may even be easier to take an export of your new site, then upload the old sites database and import the new posts into the old site.

This should handle the post content and all the tags

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of doing this would be copy contents of your older post from `phpmyadmin` and paste it in new domain and publish again. For that follow this procedure:

1. Go to `phpmyadmin` and select your database (whose post you wants to copy).
2. Click on `wp_posts` table to open it.
3. Now click on `SQL` tab (available above the table) and type following query and click on `Go` button (bottom right side).

   ```
    SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type='post'
   ```
4. Now all posts will be shown to you in tabular form (in tables).
5. Final step, All of post contents are use to store in field names as `post_content` and post title is use to store in field `post_title`.

Just copy `post_title` field's content to get title of post and copy `post_content` field's content to get description detail of posts.

You can copty it either by double click on content of field or by clicking on edit option (available on each row) and on edit page copy those fields and paste in your new domain (`dashbord -> Posts -> Add New`).

**Note**: You just need to copy only two fields (mentioned above) from `wp_posts` table.

Comment: in my older posts, I have tags on each post, how I can connect my post to my tags, and If I only copy wp_post. ID post in my older post will confilct with ID new post.

Comment: @jodkso I am not saying to copy whole `wp_posts` table. You just need to copy two fields from that table and by copy only two field there can't be any possibility on conflicting ID because after copy you gonna publish those post again so new ID will generate for them. Read whole procedure that I have shown.

Comment: by the way, I have 1000 posts in my older domain. can I do it automatically ?

Comment: my problem is, I have 1000 posts in my older domain, I can't do it manually.

Comment: @jodkso For that you have to export two tables from `phpmyadmin` named as `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`. But don't copy whole `wp_posts` table because there are `pages` also there. So Run `SQL` query that I gave you in my answer and then after query shows result then click on export tab to copy only post's data. Then Export `wp_postmeta` table. And finally import both table in new database. Yes ID may conflict, so take backup of posts from new domain and delete them because its only 10 posts and wont take long to recreate if you have backup.

Comment: @jodkso It would be better if you test this first in local server instead of live project!

Answer (score -1):

Please for next time, try to save all your articles using Notepad or [Microsoft word](https://www.virginvast.com/office-365-price/) format. That is what I normally do in every of my articles that I write in other not to be stranded if I loss any of my sites with articles to publish.

Thank you.

Sammy Jnr